# Requirements to set up a document repository for the client using SharePoint from Azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint, virtual-machine

I have to develop a document repository on SharePoint from Azure. As I have new to Azure, I  do not know about the requirements to set up the entire SharePoint and make it run like the SharePoint online, 2013, etc.

As much as I have read, it says we need a VM, a SQL server and Sharepoint. I am unsure if this all what we need and what is the role of the VM and SQL server in this.

Can anyone please share the suggestions or the experiences for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are going to host document repository, you need to check
   Office 365's OneDrive or SharePoint components. This is the PAAS
   model.
2. If you want to have a dedicated portal using full SharePoint features, you need to setup a virtual machine, on which you setup the entire installation of SharePoint just like you do on a actual server. This will be the IAAS model, where Azure just offers you hosting service for the VM. SQL server is required for hosting the backend database for SharePoint (documents, users, roles etc)

Comment: Thanks Nitin. This was really helpful to understand the requirements.

Comment: If it fits your purpose, please mark as answered or further clarify your needs. Thanks